# Creating a react app error with npm cannot find module

Tags: reactjs, json, npm, package.json

I've created many react projects and never run into this error. I've restarted my computer, cleared my npm cache, and deleted my package-lock file then npm install and nothing has worked yet. I'm running this exactly:

npx create-react-app my-app

cd my-app

These commands work as expected but when I run

npm start

I'm getting:

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/folder/my-app/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

I've tried creating multiple new projects in different folders and still am getting the same error. I've been able to successfully run these commands in the past for projects and don't think I've done anything different on my end

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `package-lock.json` and then run `npm install`

Check file `package.json` is there any file there is an entry for `main`, usually something like `"main"`: `"dist/js"`